# IronPython will not return result of an expression stored in a file

Tags: c#, expression, ironpython

I try to get the result of an expression using IronPython. The following Code works as expected:

```
var e = Python.CreateEngine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
var source = e.CreateScriptSourceFromString("1 + 2");
var compiledCode = source.Compile(new PythonCompilerOptions());
var result = compiledCode.Execute(e.CreateScope()); // result = 3
```

After executing this code `result`contains 3.
Lets change the code so that the expression comes from a file:

```
var e = Python.CreateEngine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
var source = e.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"D:\!Scripts\Test.py");
var compiledCode = source.Compile(new PythonCompilerOptions());
var result = compiledCode.Execute(e.CreateScope());
```

The content of the file is `1 + 2`.
After executing `result` is null.

Why? What's wrong?
A solution might be to load the content of a file and use `CreateScriptSourceFromString` but ... no...

Comment: This is normal behavior for most scripting engines. A top-level file does not return anything, just like any application does not return anything but an optional error code to the OS. What you want is to create a function, execute the script in a scope, then get hold of the function and call that.

Comment: Hm. I tried to have an easy way for the user to define simple expressions. In that case I'll load the whole file content and use `CreateScriptSourceFromString`. Hopefully there's no side effect using this approach.

Comment: You could read the content of a file as a string and pass that as done in your first snippet, but this tends to work only for simple programs.

Comment: I'm using IronPython as a simple script extension for my C# program. I don't expect komplex scripts. I think it will work. Thx.